No email notification option in task
Here is the short version of the issue:

I create a new task
I assign it to myself
There is no box to check for "send email notification"

I've tried to follow these instructions:

But the last step doesn't exist:


Please refer to this - 'Send Notification' checkbox not available on the Task page layout
Task assignment notification not sent when Task is assigned to the creator
